# How to give equal margins in all directions to a flexbox?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am working on a Reactjs project . I have a div (#up-coming-events) of display:flex . I want to give it equal margins in all directions . So I applied margin:auto , but however it's not giving margin to top and bottom . It's only giving margin to left and right side .
Here's my code :-
UpCommingEvent.js :-

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles/upcommingevent.css"
function UpCommingEvent() {
  return (
    <div id="up-coming-events">
      <div id="event-thumbnail"></div>
      <p>hello upComming eventts here</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default UpCommingEvent;
```

upcommingevent.css:-

```
#up-coming-events {
  width: 88rem;
  margin: auto; /*Not giving margins in to top and bottom */
  height: 35rem;
  border: 2px solid white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2.875rem;
}
#event-thumbnail {
  width: 38.7rem;
  height: 23.6rem;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

I am thinking to hard code the top & bottom margins , equal to the left & right margins , but I think there will be a more smarter & efficient way to do it .

May anyone tell me what that smarter & efficient way is ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can set margin explicitly:

```
#up-coming-events {
  width: 88rem;
  margin: 1rem; 
  height: 35rem;
  border: 2px solid white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2.875rem;
}
#event-thumbnail {
  width: 38.7rem;
  height: 23.6rem;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

[and this is of the recommended ways](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin)

Comment: Ya..I am also thinking for the same , but I thought let check ones on the internet , is there any better way to do it .

Comment: @RishabhRaghwendra this is one of [the recommended ways](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin)

Comment: yup sure..why not

Comment: you may also upvote my question if you think , my question is valuable to be answered

Comment: @RishabhRaghwendra Sure, it is well formatted! Feel free to choose a reply to mark as answer to simplify the future search of other users.

Answer (score 0):

The margin auto only work for lateral margin properties. If you want set the same margin you should use a relative margin like value%.

Comment: What do you mean by lateral margin properties ?

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using flex box, then you can align anything (vertically or horizontally) quite painlessly with the align-items, align-self, and justify-content properties. Phil Walton does a great job describing the solution:

https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

Comment: But this tells us how to center a flexbox items not a flexbox . I want to center the "#up-coming-events" div .

Comment: Then you should make the parent element of #up-coming-events a flex box and consider the child the nested element.  Set the parent element to 'display: flex' and the up-coming-events should use the align-items, align-self, and justify-content properties.

Comment: I was thinking like there will be any hack which can do this without making a parent element for #up-comming-events  , but anyways . Thanks buddy